# Can't locate Date/Parse.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

getting following error while running my perl scirpt.

`Can't locate Date/Parse.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.1 /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.1 /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.16.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.16.1 /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl .) at ../../tools/replace_tenant_json_data.pl line 27.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ../../tools/replace_tenant_json_data.pl line 27.`

From above error I infer perl looks into wrong dir for modules.
The right directory is   /System/Library/Perl/5.16

command env –I perl –V is different form perl –V

```
`env –I perl –V
 @INC:
/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Library/Perl/5.16
/Network/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Network/Library/Perl/5.16
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2
/System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/5.16
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16

perl –V
@INC:
/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.1
/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.1
/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.16.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.16.1
/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl
/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl`
```

Comment: Are you sure you installed `Date::Parse` from CPAN?

Comment: Thankyou Nigoro. After running cpan Date::parse I am not getting the error. I got lost in the errors I saw. If you can clarify why env -i perl -V is different from perl -V that would be great

Comment: If it can not find it, there are two things to look at the spelling which appears correct and if you installed in the proper path that line is looking at. One way you can look is to use shell util find to locate the Date::Parse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@NigoroJr gave the right hint in the comment under the main question (`cpan Date::Parse`) but I'll expound upon the differences in the `perl -V` outputs.

From the Darwin man page for `env`:

```
SYNOPSIS
     env [-i] [name=value ...] [utility [argument ...]]

DESCRIPTION
     env executes utility after modifying the environment as specified on the command line.  The option
     name=value specifies an environmental variable, name, with a value of value.  The option '-i' causes
     env to completely ignore the environment it inherits.
```

So, when you run `env -i perl -V`, you get a blank/default environment, which is picking up the system-installed perl.  When you run just `perl -V', you get the version you're actually using, which looks like something you installed.

BTW, it looks like your active Perl is an *older* rev than the one the system provides, so maybe you should consider switching back to the system-provided Perl.